# ¿Estaria bien este codigo?

Tags: python-3.7

'''
Se tiene una escala de calificaciones que se desea modificar
por otra escala.

Los valores [0,10], deben ser mapeados a una escala con 5 rangos.

[0,4] => R  (de Reprobado)

(4,6) => D  (de Desaprobado)

[6,7) =>A (de Aprobado)

[7,8) =>B (de Bueno)

[8,10] =>E (de Excelente)
'''

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
print('#--------------------------------INICIANDO----------------------------#')
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    try: 
       nota = float(input('Ingrese una nota: '))
       if nota>=0 and nota<=10:
           if nota>=0 and nota<=4:
               print('R')
           elif nota>4 and nota<6:
               print('D')
           elif nota>=6 and nota<7:
               print('A')
           elif nota>=7 and nota<8:
               print('B')
           else:
               print('E')
       else:
            print('La nota ingresado no es valida')
    
    except ValueError:
        print('Error, ah ingresado una letra')
    print('#-------------------------------FINALIZADO----------------------------#')
```

Comment: ¿Tienes algún problema con el código? Hasta donde veo está bien. Solo ten cuidado con la identación: el bloque de try debes colocarlo bien atrás. Igual el último print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Tienes algún problema con el código? Hasta donde veo está bien. Solo ten cuidado con la identación: el bloque de try debes colocarlo bien atrás. Igual el último print.

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
print('#--------------------------------INICIANDO----------------------------#')
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

try: 
   nota = float(input('Ingrese una nota: '))
   if nota>=0 and nota<=10:
       if nota>=0 and nota<=4:
           print('R')
       elif nota>4 and nota<6:
           print('D')
       elif nota>=6 and nota<7:
           print('A')
       elif nota>=7 and nota<8:
           print('B')
       else:
           print('E')
   else:
        print('La nota ingresado no es valida')

except ValueError:
    print('Error, ah ingresado una letra')
print('#-------------------------------FINALIZADO----------------------------#')
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder

Comment: Si te sirvió la respuesta colócala como aceptada y da su voto, para que otros de la comunidad también puedan considerarla útil.